# Powershell CMDLET Cross Domain Managment

Tags: powershell

I'm logged in at domain "domain1" with my account. I wish via powershell to be able to update users in domain "domain2" via my supe ruser account "suaccount" with password "password1". Trust is established between the two.

Running PowerShell 2.0 and .NET 3.5 SP1

I have gotten this far:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
$ctype = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain
$context = New-Object -TypeName     
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext -ArgumentList $ctype, "domain2", "OU=TestOU,DC=domain2", "suaccount", "password1"

$usr = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal -ArgumentList $context

$usr.Name = "AM Test1"
$usr.DisplayName = "AM Test1"
$usr.GivenName = "AM"
$usr.SurName = "Test1"
$usr.SamAccountName = "AMTest1"
$usr.UserPrincipalName = "amtest1@mtest.test"

$usr.PasswordNotRequired = $false
$usr.SetPassword("errr")
$usr.Enabled = $true

$usr.Save()
```

Pretty new to PowerShell, any pointers? I want to edit/create users on the "other" domain so to speak.

I get the error:

```
"Exception calling "Save" with "0" argument(s): "General access denied error
"
At C:\Script\Sandbox\Morris PowerShell Application\includes\mo\mo.ps1:104 char:14
+     $usr.Save <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException"
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Does domain 2 trust domain 1?

Comment: Yes a trust is established betweeen the two!

Comment: What is the FQDN of Domain2 ??

Comment: I cannot type it here I'm sorry, however it is in the likes of "domain.local", I know I wrote "OU=TestOU,DC=domain2" it is actually "DC=domain2,DC=local" however I know the address is correct otherwise another error pops up explaining that the domain cannot be found etc.etc. Same goes for the user credentials, I get the "unknown user/bad password" error.

Comment: Try using for username this format domain2\username, and always use the FQDN for the domain.

Comment: "domain2\username" was what was keeping me back, works now! Thank you for your input Christian! What a tab eh haha. Never stop learning do you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments: Try using for username this format domain2\username, and always use the FQDN for the domain. – Christian yesterday